# Ember replacing html content

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I've just started learning ember am trying to make a link that replaces other html, currently I have written this:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="about">
    {{#each}}
    <h2>{{#link-to 'quarter' this}}{{title}}{{/link-to}}</h2>
    {{/each}}
</script>
```

Now I want to make the quarter content load in the same about template replacing that each loop, how should I go about it?

Again, I'm totally new to ember and it's own guides section is a bit too convoluted for me to find the answer.

Comment: Can you precise what content? Do you mean the content of the quarter show page? Do you want this to display in a 'master/slave' layout?

Comment: Yes, the content of quarters page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since About is not a resource route, you have to use custom outlet in your about template:

```
<div class="quarter">{{outlet quarter}}</div>
```

Then in your QuarterRoute:

```
App.QuarterRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  renderTemplate: function() {
    this.render({ outlet: 'quarter' });
  }
});
```

If you have a Quarters resource routes, you could just nest your routes and just a have simple outlet in your quarters template.

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('quarters', function() {
    this.resource('quarter');
  });
});
```

Comment: For my example about is a resource route and I've already tried nesting the quarter in about route. But doing so doesn't replace the about content it only appends the quarter contents

Comment: resource routes should always be a plural if i'm not mistakened, that's why its not working. I guess you could have a quarters route with a custom path "about". Then nest your quarter route in it. Then no need of custom outlet

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding me, it's working, the outlet is appending data to the about page and does the same if I change about to quarters, the point is that I want it to replace all of the about/quarters pages content with quarter content. Appreciate the help.

Comment: Then just create a non nested quarter resource routes. This will render the quarter page using the main root outlet